# Kafka docker compose external connection

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I want to expost 9093 to outside of the docker container. When I set the kafka-0 ports exposed to 9093 and the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS as follow, i am unable to connect to localhost:9093 as shown in the following docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  kafka-0:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1
    container_name: kafka-0
    hostname: kafka-0
    ports:
      - "9093:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=wise-nlp-zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka-0:29094,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9093
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.3.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2182:2181"
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
```

However, when i change to

```
ports:
 - "9092:9092"
```

and

```
- KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka-0:29094,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```

I am able to connect to kafka broker localhost:9092.

How can i change external port to 9093 for applications to connect? I want to set up multiple brokers.

Comment: where is your port 29094 from?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Why's it not working currently?

Advertised listener(s) (as defined in `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`) are the *host and port that the broker returns to the client in its initial connection for it to use in subsequent connections*.

If you want external clients to use 9093 then `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=…PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9093` is correct. *However*, you've not configured your `KAFKA_LISTENERS`, which if you check the broker log when it starts up will default to the value set by `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`:

```
kafka-0      |  listeners = PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:29094,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9093
```

So in this state, the broker is listening on port 9093, but with this Docker Compose instruction you've redirected external connections into the container on 9093 to 9092 within the container:

```
    ports: 
      - "9093:9092"
```

```
➜ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             … PORTS                                        NAMES
8b934ef4145c        confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.1       … 0.0.0.0:9093->9092/tcp                       kafka-0
```

So your external connections will go to port 9092 *in* the container—and the broker is not listening on this port. You can verify this with `nc`:

```
-- Port 9093 is open on the host machine
➜ nc -vz localhost 9093
Connection to localhost port 9093 [tcp/*] succeeded!

-- Port 9092 is _not_ open on the Kafka container
➜ docker exec -it kafka-0 nc -vz localhost 9092
localhost [127.0.0.1] 9092 (?) : Connection refused
```

❌ You'll see that a client connection fails

```sh
➜ kafkacat -b localhost:9093 -L
% ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Broker transport failure
```

### How can you fix it?

You can either:

1. Change the listener to be on the port that you target with the Docker port redirect. This will work but personally I think is more confusing.
2. Change the Docker port redirect to target the port on which the listener is on. This is the option I would use as it is clearer (e.g. port `9093` is used throughout, rather than mixing `9092` and `9093` together)

#### Option 1: Change the listener to be on the port that you target with the Docker port redirect

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  kafka-0:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.1
    container_name: kafka-0
    ports:
      - "9093:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka-0:29094,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9093
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:29094,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.4.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2182:2181"
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
```

✅Test:

```
➜ kafkacat -b localhost:9093 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1: localhost:9093/1):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1 at localhost:9093 (controller)
```

#### Option 2: Change the Docker port redirect to target the port on which the listener is on

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  kafka-0:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.1
    container_name: kafka-0
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka-0:29094,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9093
      # If you don't specify KAFKA_LISTENERS it will default to the ports used in
      # KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS, but IMO it's better to be explicit about these settings
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:29094,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9093
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.4.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2182:2181"
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
```

✅Test

```sh
➜ kafkacat -b localhost:9093 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1: localhost:9093/1):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1 at localhost:9093 (controller)
```

### Connecting to Kafka from *within* the Docker network

The examples above are about connecting to Kafka from the *Docker host*. If you want to connect to it from *within the Docker network* (e.g. another container) you need to use `kafka-0:29094` as the broker host and IP. If you try to use `localhost:9093` then the client container will resolve `localhost` to its own container, and thus fail.

### Multiple brokers

[See here](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/74eb51937801a1125d50ee44f9996c6fbe063d83/sonos/docker-compose.yml#L1-L67) for an example Docker Compose with multiple Kafka brokers.

### References

https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: But, the same question, where is the port 29094 from? IMO, it is the port used in container.

Comment: @Vincent 29094 is just an arbitrary number used for one of the listener ports.

Comment: the port mapping of kafka-0 is "9093:9093", so in the container, the port should be 9093. No?

Comment: @Vincent feel free to open a new question about this :)